# Get Server Url of active word document

Tags: c#, vsto

I am developing a VSTO add-in for Microsoft word to show the information of the file in a task pane that is loaded from a cloud storage service. To open/save the file i am using a third part file picker that allows a user to open/save file directly to/from the cloud storage service. i tried to get path of the document that is currently loaded in Microsoft word by

```
string path = this.Application.ActiveDocument.Path;
```

it shows a path like (C:\user\abcuser\appdata\temp\abc.docx) which obviously doesn't provide any idea about directory structure maintained on cloud storage service account of the user.

Is there any way to get the server Url (e.g. https://www.cloudstorage.com/directory/abc.docs) of the document that is currently loaded in office App from a server/Cloud storage rather than the temporary path described above??
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not gathering this data directly from your picker class?

Comment: I don't have the code for picker, it is installed separately which acts as an add-in in Microsoft office.